Sci-Fi from 60's to mid 70's about an invisible creature
I watched this mid to late 70's on TV, the story was about a group of people searching for a lost treasure, hidden by Indians I think, some time ago; when they find it, it is protected by an invisible creature that is released by their discovery, it then proceeds to attack and kill most of them until, when trying to escape in a jeep, they are attacked again and during this a fuel drum in the back of the jeep is set alight and burns the creature to death. In the flames and smoke you finally get a look at the silhouette of the creature dying. 

Sounds like Sound of Horror (1964). From Wiki:

archaeologist Dr. Pete Asilov and Professor Andre attempt to detonate dynamite in an abandoned mountain cave, uncovering petrified eggs in the blasts. Taking one they fail to notice another had rolled off and hatched, releasing a reptilian creature that vanishes... there is gold hidden in the cave... 

And in the end:

the creature reveals itself to be on top of the car which forces them to pull over. Dorman ignites the fuel reserves in the back of the jeep, destroying himself and the creature in a massive ball of fire. 

The creature is invisible, but it's seen briefly as it burns to death in the end. The trailer, as well as the movie itself, are available on Youtube.

Serendipitously, I came across this flick a few days ago after reading a different question: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19517/can-you-tell-me-the-title-of-this-horror-movie
